# Clear excel cell by vba code

Tags: excel-2010

I am trying to clear a cell in excel based on value in another cell via vba code:
**Like: if C20 is >=500000, than E22 be clear.**
This has to be automatic, for each time the value is less than 500000, the cell E22 has to be blank.

Please help.
James

Comment: Does **C20** contain a *formula* or a *constant* ??

Comment: C20 contain a constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this *Event* macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C20")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value < 500000 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("E22").Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks, i add the code, but C20 will aways have value, only for value less than 500000, will make E22 clear.